# How to add/show all Interfaces in Wireshark?

Tags: wireshark

I downloaded **[Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)** on my PC running Windows 10 and I can only see 1 interface that's associated with my PC. I'm in my home and I want to see even other interfaces like my smartphone, or my laptop.

How can I add those interfaces? I didn't find anything on internet that could help me. I saw a video on Youtube where a guy had all his network interfaces showing, so I'm sure I can add them.

Found something online saying I need privileges, but I already ran Wireshark as Administrator and nothing changed. Please help. Thanks!

This is how Wireshark looks as soon as I start it:

[image]

Comment: Then you need to install wireshark on your laptop or your smartphone. If you installed wireshark on your PC, you will see the interface(s) that's available on your PC. Make sure you installed WinPcap as well when you installed wireshark

Comment: I wanted to monitor all data/packets of my devices connected to my network, so I can't with 1 PC? and how this guy here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xW9GDAJXB-I at 0:23 got all these network interfaces?

Comment: You need an ethernet switch that can do port mirroring, then you can mirror the packets of the port your other device is connected to and view the copy of those packets on your PC. The guy in the video has a few network cards, bluetooth dongles as well as a handful of virtual devices that exists on linux that he can capture packets on, all on his local PC. A capture device is a device on the PC you run wireshark on where packets travel through, it's not another gadget that you own.

Comment: Alright all clear now, I'm learning though! So what I wanted to do was like running Wireshark inside my router xD(*Ideally*). I really appreciate your patience in helping me, thank you very much !!

Now you can stop read though because what I will say is out of the main argument for which I asked, really thank you again.

Comment: taking up what you said, I think that.. so there is a device (a type of switch I think) that send all data coming from different ports to a main port (physical port) where a PC is connected, so you can monitor the network with program such as Wireshark, and the PC who is taking all of those "mirrors packet" will be very "congested" and slow trying to do whatever it use that cable? So if you don't use that pc just for monitoring and if we add to it another network card it works fine?

Comment: I really don't know much about this, didn't study anything yet I'm 18y old, these are just my thought based on what you said. I mean it all started when I was tired of lagging while playing online so I decided to find a program that allows you monitoring your network to see what devices are taking a % of the band provided, but it's not just for playing without lagg but also for learning new think since I'll be an IT guy. (sorry for my english hope you clearly understood what I said).
Now I final ask you if there is a program that allow you to see what devices are using most of the band.

Comment: Afterall it's interesting how only when you got problems you grow up and learn things you wouldn't learn if you didn't have problems. I mean I always get tired of the quality of Italian connections but in the end it's worth since I'm learning. Well now if you are reading and trying to asking all mine '?' you are a really great man I really appreciate it so much that I would pay! thanks you !

Answer (score 0):

1- Download the Win10Pcap which is a new WinPcap-based Ethernet packet capture library. from (http://www.win10pcap.org/download/)
2- Run Wireshark form an administrator account.